# What are the correct step by step commands for gitflow workflow?

Tags: git, github, git-flow, github-flow

- **What does one complete lifecycle of gitflow look like?**
- **Which branch is pushed to production: `release` or `main`**?

I have done deep research on this topic. But these were the questions whose answers I couldn't find.
Any suggestion gratefully received. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly _is_ the question?

Comment: @matt What does one complete lifecycle of gitflow look like? How are the rules implemented through commands

Comment: @matt Please feel free to edit the question, if you want to make it better

Comment: No, _you_ need to edit it and make it better. I don't know how to make it better because I can't make sense of it. It seems to ask a dozen unrelated and not very meaningful questions. Please ask just one simple clear question if you want help.

Comment: @matt Please see if it now clear.  Actually, I have many questions very closly related to the same topic. So, I thought, it would be better to add them in one post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commonly "master" or "main" is pushed to prod as it's a form of a "stable" release. though this also depends on the type of project/where its used type of deal, internally a company will use the method above, but as an open-source repo it is common for a release to be used instead.

In my own development experience, a base repo will be created. Developers will make branches for features, hotfixes, etc... etc... and then put a PR into a staging environment which once stable and passes unit tests (via CI/CD) will be deployed.

Unsure if this helps much, but is what I think when this question is brought up.

Comment: Can u please answer this question: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70858547/which-workflow-is-more-compatible-with-webapp-deployment-on-heroku-gitflow-or-g)

Comment: what is the difference: `git checkout -b develop main` or `git checkout -b develop`

Comment: what does "feature" mean in `git checkout -b feature/MYFEATURE develop`

Comment: [Git's](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout) Documentation actually does a good job explaining this:

``git checkout -b [<new-branch>] [<start-point>]`` as far as ``feature/MYFEATURE`` its just a branch name.